# Is it possible to create stackexchange-openid from an email account which already has openid

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I access my stackexchange account stackoverflow,meta etc from **myopenid** which is linked to my gmail.

Recently, i read in stackexchange(*don't remember the link*) that myopenid will soon be closed and will no longer be supported by SE, so, stackexcahnge.openid is a better option.So i tried creating a stackexchange openid from my existing gmail account but it would always say that `email account already in use`.

**So what i want to know is that** can i not create a stackexchnage openid from my gmail account if it already has a open-id (*i.e., myopenid* ) registered on that mail, *if not* what should i do to create stackexchange open id as email id is must and i only have one email!!

Comment: Have you tried to [reset your password](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) and then use "Log in using Stack Exchange" at the login page?